# How to configure the custom options in pfSense for OpenVPN to access the LAN

Tags: networking, routing, lan, openvpn, pfsense

In the Advanced Configuration section of pfSense's OpenVPN, in Custom Options, there's an example to push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0".

In my network, my OpenVPN server uses the 10.22.4.0/24 subnet to tunnel clients, and the LAN network which I want them to have access to is 10.22.1.0/24. What command should I include in the Custom Options to allow VPN clients to access the LAN.

I will appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Route pushing isn't always required.... I have several ranges setup and I don't have anything defined in Advanced Configuration.

I would personally go to the `Firewall > Rules > OpenVPN` and make sure you can communicate from OpenVPN clients to the subnet you want to access

Comment: Hi @William Hilsum, thank you for your answer. This is what I though at the beginning. I have been several days working on this and haven't been able to access any IP on the LAN address (my VPN clients seem to only get an IP from the tunnel range).
Would you mind to provide an example of a Firewall rule to see if I am doing it correctly?

Comment: Hi @DAVID - It's hard to provide a relevant example - and - my rule list is huge/used for a production environment... If you have a few minutes some time tomorrow, feel free to look at my profile and get in contact... If I have time, I'll be happy to take a look and help you offline (then post a more relevant answer here later to help others).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any "advanced configuration" set in my OpenVPN setup (pfSense 2.4, but it's been set up since 2.1.5 or so with no changes to the VPN setup.)

There's a rule to permit the tunnel network to talk to the LAN, and vice versa. There's a rule to allow connections to come in on the WAN. I think that's it.